# Is there a way to only display frames from a video that only have detected object bounding boxes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, yolo, yolov5

I'm using a video for testing my custom yolov5s object detection model on test data. However, not every frame in the video has a valid object to be detected.

[ When the inference testing is ran on the video, the image below shows when the model finds a frame that has an object that can be detected and classified[image: [1]]

As you can see, frame 4401 has detected a yield traffic sign but frame 4399 and 4400 haven't detected anything. My question is how do I process through 4500 frames of a video and only display frames that have detected objects. I have extracted the frames as JPEGS but only want the valid JPEGS to evaluate test performance? Better still, is it possible to extract the data from relevant frames to a text file?

If anyone could help me out this would be a great help and time saver, many thanks in advance.

[the new error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3AmM.png)

Comment: You can check the length of the bounding boxes, and create an `if` condition over `cv2.imshow()` to only display the frame `if len(bboxes):`

Comment: @MuhammadHuzaifa sounds like what I'm looking for, I'm generating this in google colab 3, however I'm not the best at coding but ill give it a go. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @MuhammadHuzaifa I've managed to distignuish the frames that have labelled bounding boxes in them by saving the txt bounding box coords found and put them into txt files, which then gives me an insight into what frame has labels and which ones don't since the txt files are saved as 00321.txt therefore I know frame 321 has a bounding box. is there a way to call the images that only have associated txt files?

Comment: I am on phone ATM, so I mistakenly replied as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from shutil import move
import os

txt_dir = "txtfiles"
images_folder = "images_folder"
move_des = "move_imgs_path"

for file in os.listdir(txt_dir):
    if file.endswith('txt'):
          frame_name = file.split('.')[0]+ ".jpeg"
          print(frame_name)
          move(os.path.join(images_folder, frame_name), move_des)
```

Comment: I've already saved the frames as images, however not all images saved are necessary for test evaluation because not every frame has an object for my model to detect. therefore i was wondering after inference was done,how do i discard the frames that haven't got anything detected in them. if that is possible is there was a way to only display the jpegs (which used to be frames) that have detected objects in them. Does that make sense haha?

Comment: Yes, it makes perfect sense now. What names did you give to the jpegs when you were saving them? Do they have frame numbers in their names?

Comment: Yeah they are saved as the frame number, like 00032.jpg

Comment: If the images and the corresponding txt files are saved with the same names (i. e. frame no.), then it can be easily done by iterating over the txt files and moving the images with those names to another directory.

Comment: would you be able to try and give me some example code to work with, im a bit new to python? many thanks in advance if you can

Comment: I have updated the answer with the code. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: You have made my day so much easier! Thank you

Comment: I'm glad to be of help

Comment: @Muhammed Huzaifa is there a way to ignore if an image doesnt exist in the images folder, because i think its only moving the file if a corresponding txt file exists.

Comment: the image "the new error" in the updated question above ^, at the bottom to help understand my new error

Comment: I know it's late, but I have been busy. You can simply add exception handling to handle this error. Please read a little about exception handling in Python.

Comment: Another way to do would be to use the `os` module's `os.path.isfile(fname)`.